# Winscp to Linux guest SCP account, access denied

Tags: linux, permissions, sftp, scp

I'm trying to set up a restricted SFTP account on a Kali Linux box so that I can have random co-workers dump files without having to give them a ton of access (or my password). I followed the directions here: https://www.maketecheasier.com/use-sftp-transfer-files-linux-servers/
to create an sftpuser account and download folder. I created the group, gave the group and user ownership and permissions of and to the folders, specified it in /etc/sshd_config with the following lines

```
   Match Group sftp_group
   ChrootDirectory /home/sftpuser/uploadedfiles
   ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

I use systemctl start ssh.socket to turn it on, then when I try to winscp in using the sftpuser account, I get an access denied. I can winscp in just fine using my main account, but I've missed something or misconfigured something with the sftpuser. Anyone know what I might need to do to fix it? Do I have to specify the allowed folder in the winscp connection somehow? Do I need to add more permissions to the sftp_group or sftpuser? Or add another line in sshd_config or something? Or maybe comment one out? I've been googling around and looking at different guides and I'm not sure why it's failing at the very initial authentication stage. I even did a passwd command on the user to reset the password and make sure that the password was correct.

Edit: in /etc/passwd the user shows up like this:

```
sftpuser:x:1001:1001::/home/sftpuser:/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

(as I type this out, maybe this is the issue? The path may be wrong, I think in this distro it maybe should be /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server? at least that's what is listed as Subsystem in sshd_config).
-- I changed the shell, still get an authentication error.
group shows up as

```
sftp:group:x:1002:sftpuser
```

the permissions for the folder and sub folder are as follows

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 root   sftp_group   4096   Jul 13   10:36 sftpuser
```

then within the sftpuser folder:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 sftpuser   sftp_group   4096   Jul 13 10:36 uploadedfiles
```

Comment: You have lots of questions, but very little real data in your post. You need to supply much more info for an answer.

Comment: @harrymc Not sure what else to add? If I use winscp to connect to my linux machine with my main user account and password, it connects just fine, and if I do it with sftpuser, I get an access denied. I don't even know how to go about troubleshooting an access denied error for sftp at that early of a stage of the process, and Google-fu has not helped. I could add all the steps from the link I suppose?

Comment: More hard data about your configuration, accounts, permissions. Please Edit it into your post instead of in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ChrootDirectory /home/sftpuser/uploadedfiles
drwxr-xr-x 3 root   sftp_group   4096   Jul 13   10:36 sftpuser
drwxr-xr-x 2 sftpuser   sftp_group   4096   Jul 13 10:36 uploadedfiles
```

The `ChrootDirectory` and its parent directories must be owned by root (and not writable by group or other). In your case, you probably want to make the chroot directory `/home/sftpuser` instead of `/home/sftpuser/uploadedfiles`.

Comment: Edit: Oh wait, I just noticed it's an option in the sshd_config file, duh. I'll change that and report bck... Edit2: Aha, that fixed it. Thank you so much! I'm not sure I understand the chroot directory relationship though and why that broke it?